# jQuery $.each duplicates info

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this is my `app.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON("/info.php", function(json){

        $.each(json, function(i, player){
            //console.log(player.response.players[0].avatarfull);

       $(".userinfo").append('<img style="width: 100px; height: 100px" style="width: 100px; height: 100px" src="'+player.response.players[0].avatarfull+'">');
       $(".steamProfile").append('<a href="'+player.response.players[0].profileurl+'">STEAM nuoroda</a>');
       $(".personaname").append(player.response.players[0].personaname);
       });

    });
});
```

This is my `html`

```
<div class="col-md-4">

<div class="userinfo"></div>
<p>Slapyvardis: <strong><span id="personaname"></span></strong></p>
<p>Vardas: <strong>{{$s->fname}} {{$s->lname}}</strong></p>
@if($s->facebook == "")
<p>Facebook: <strong>Nėra</strong></p>
@else
<p>Facebook: <strong>{{$s->facebook}}</strong></p>
@endif
<p>Skype ID: <strong>{{$s->skype_id}}</strong></p>
<p>Steam ID: <strong><span class="steamID">{{$s->steam_id}}</span></strong></p>
<p>Steam URL: <strong><span class="steamProfile"></span></strong></p>

<p style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;"><button id="reason" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reasonText{{$s->id}}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></i> Rodyti priežastį</button>

<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#proofText{{$s->id}}" id="proof" class="btn btn-success">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> <strong>Įrodymai</strong></button>

<form id="voteUp" action="/minus-rep/{{$s->id}}" method="get">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i> <strong>Nerekomenduoti</strong></button>
</form>

</p>
<p>Nerekomenduoja: <strong><span id="votes" class="label label-success">{{$s->points}}</span></strong>

@if($s->points < 2 && $s->points > 0) 
    narys
@endif
@if($s->points > 1 && $s->points < 10)
    nariai
@endif
@if($s->points > 10)
    narių
@endif  
</p>
</div>
```

And this is how result is displayed:

[THE RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Uga.png)
[image: The Result]

It basically duplicates the info and displays it in the same column. Can you give me any suggestion to fix this problem ? I was searching the answers but I can't append them to my code...

**The avatars are duplicating. It should be only green and in next column the anime avatar**

`json`

```
$data = [];

    foreach($row as $r){

    $steamids = $r['steam_id'];

    $APIKEY = '***';
    $steamAPI = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?steamids=$steamids&key=$APIKEY&format=json";
    $json_object= file_get_contents($steamAPI);
    $data[] = json_decode($json_object);

}
    echo json_encode($data);
```

**Console.log response**

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8888/info.php"

https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/20/20a65e6289bfbbbf59d4fdb923ad4daf8ca4fd9d_full.jpg

https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/1a/1ae5d70c309e3f9f31bb6cff6104d4dd6e08abcc_full.jpg
```

Comment: I don't understand what's duplicated. Can you make jsfiddle or plnkr?

Comment: The avatars in the picture. Its green and the next avatar @Martin

Comment: I doesn't look duplicated, there're different names and Steam Ids

Comment: Names and Steam ids I get from database not from json. The avatars is duplicated. THE GREEN AVATAR and THE ANIMER AVATAR. The green should be in first column and the anime avatar in next column @Martin

Comment: can you post entire content of the ajax response? I mean the `json` variable.

Comment: I don't have Steam API key, I can test it by myself.

Comment: You can post your API key here. Post just the JSON response from the server.

Comment: @Martin I have updated my answer again.

Comment: That's not a json response. I'm sure the server doesn't return this.

Comment: `console.log(json)` returns `[Object, Object] [Object, Object]` the only problem is displaying avatars. Maybe there are some commands ? All the info I'm getting correctly @Martin

Comment: @Martin If I write all html code to javascript file it displays fine

Answer (score 1):

Tough to say without knowing what that response is but I think you might be directly referencing a member of the array using the key '0' so it's looping through 2 players but only using data for the first. Instead of

```
player.response.players[0]...
```

How about

```
player.response.players[i]...
```

Comment: No, thats not a case. Something is with display wrong here

Comment: I'll only get green avatar if I do with `[i]`